# Protractor testing i cant get acces to input value using sendkeys

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, protractor, angular-test

i cant sendkeys to the following input (only here i fail, the rest are work).
i get error message:

```
StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

code:

```
test('Should insert an invalid password', async done => {
        const css = by.css('[id=password111]')
        const password = await element(css)
        await password.clear()
        await password.sendKeys('tom')
        // await submitForm()
        done()
    })
```

html:

```
<nz-input-group [id]="'passwordContainer'" [nzSuffix]="passwordSuffixTemplate" nzSize="large">
    <input [id]="'password111'"
           class="cdf-input"
           [type]="passwordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'"
           nz-input
           nzSize="large"
           [required]="passwordAuth"
           [formControlName]="'password'"
           [placeholder]="'Password'"
    />
</nz-input-group>
```

who has idea where i wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Use expected conditions to wait for staleness.

```
const expected = require('protractor').ExpectedConditions
browser.wait(expected.stalenessOf(loc.customer_login),undefined,'msg')
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf

refer this link to understand stale element reference error: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```js
before() {
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
}
test('Should insert an invalid password', async () => {
        const css = by.css('[id=password111]')
        const password = element(css)
         password.clear()
         password.sendKeys('tom')
        // await submitForm()
    })
```

Note:  You cannot use async and done callback both at the same time.
For more info visit this link https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts